# Reassign “shutdown” button on ASUS notebook

Tags: opensuse, keyboard

I want to buy an ASUS notebook, but all new notebooks have a "shutdown" button instead of "end" at the top right corner of the keyboard.

[image]

Is there any way to reassign this "shutdown" button to "end" functionality in openSUSE?

Comment: Which distro, desktop environment do you use?

Comment: Depends on how the shutdown button is handled. Run `evtest` as root, see if you have `Power Button` or similar sources, see if one of them reacts when you press the shutdown button. Also test with normal keyboard event source. Edit question with output, if you get one. Also try `acpi_listen`.

Comment: This request made me remember this - https://xkcd.com/1172/ - LOL